# load grid panel into content panel

Tags: extjs

I try to understand the basics of the extjs MVC.

I created the example app with the Sencha CMD. This comes with some basic things. What i try to make is a panel with a toolbar where i have a menu. When i click on a item in the menu i want to load a grid into the panel.

What function do i need to do this?

This is my mainmodel

```
Ext.define('JustRent.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'JustRent.view.main.MainController',
        'JustRent.view.main.MainModel',
        'JustRent.view.main.ProductenType'
    ],

    xtype: 'app-main',

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    items: [{
            region: 'center',
            id: 'contentBlock',
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'JustRental',

            dockedItems: [{
                        xtype: 'toolbar',
                        dock: 'top',
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Menu',
                            menu: {

                                xtype: 'menu',
                                items: [{
                                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                                    text: 'verhuur',
                                    menu: { 
                                    xtype: 'menu',
                                items: [{
                                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                                    text: 'Offertes',
                                    menu: {
                                        xtype: 'menu',
                                        items: [{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Overzicht'
                                        },{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Nieuwe offerte'
                                        },{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Openstaande offertes'
                                        },{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Geannuleerde offertes'
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                                    text: 'Projecten',
                                    menu: {
                                        xtype: 'menu',
                                        items: [{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Overzicht'
                                        }]
                                    }
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                                    text: 'Producten',
                                    menu: {
                                        xtype: 'menu',
                                        items: [{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Overzicht'
                                        },{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Artikelen'
                                        },{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Groepen'
                                        },{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Type',
                                    handler: 'onClickButton',
                                        },{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Soort'
                                        },{
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Merk'
                                        }]
                                    }

                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                                    text: 'Klanten'
                                }]

                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                                    text: 'verkoop'
                                }
                                ]



                            }
                        }]


                }]



        }
    ]
});
```

when i click on an item i use a basic handler. This is located in my mainController file:

```
Ext.define('JustRent.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    requires: [

    ],

    alias: 'controller.main',

    onClickButton: function () {
        console.log('click works');



    }
});
```

this is my ProductenType

```
Ext.define('JustRent.view.main.ProductenType', {

    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.ProductenType',
     requires: [
        // alerts
    ],



            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'string',
                    text: 'String'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'number',
                    text: 'Number'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'datecolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'date',
                    text: 'Date'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'booleancolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'bool',
                    text: 'Boolean'
                }
            ]




        });
```

but now is my question how can i load the JustRent.view.main.ProductenType into the panel with the id 'contenBlock'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a **Viewport** as my main container

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport

with a **border layout** http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Border

and then use **add** http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport-method-add

and **remove** methods http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport-method-remove

for component manipulation within the Viewport

*pro tip: avoid unnecessary over nesting of components, use the lighter Component possible in each case. e.g containers are lighter in the DOM compared to panels so if you only need a container don't use a panel (not saying this is the case) .*

Also I recommend Extjs in Action, awesome book that will help you really understand the framework.

Comment: Thanks i will change the panels to container. Lighter is always better :)